# Напишите программу, находящую корни квадратного уравнения {ax^2+bx+c = 0}ax 2 +bx+c=0 Java

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Такая вот проблема помогите выводит нули после точки надо без как на фото.

Comment: Просьба в дальшейнем всегда прикладывать код в явном виде (с использованием средств форматирования stack overflow), а не с помощью скринов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%.1f %.1f", s1, l1);`

Comment: не ты вообще нули вырубил мне

Comment: там на 2 фотографий видно что мне надо

Comment: Обновил ответ. По формулировке вашего вопроса это было не совсем понятно:
"_выводит нули после точки надо без как на фото._"

Comment: вроде все правильно но не проходит я не знаю как это решать

Comment: Вы используете формулу дискриминанта, а вам ваше предлагается воспользоваться теоремой Виета. В связи с особенностями хранения чисел с плавающей точкой в java ([по стандарту IEEE 754](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/) хранится не абсолютное значение) результат может незначительно отличаться. Попробуйте использовать теорему Виета и выводить как раньше без доп форматирования, предложенного мною.

Comment: Также перепроверьте, что дробная часть числа у вас выводится с точкой, а не с запятой (`Locale.US` должно решать эту проблему).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: огромное вам СПАСИБО!